# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axiom/om/OMXMLBuilderFactory

Tags: java, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to bring the tomcat server up in my  system . The version is 7.0. I'm getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axiom/om/OMXMLBuilderFactory`.

Kindly help us in solving the problem. The error comes at server start up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing a dependency of `org/apache/axiom/om/OMXMLBuilderFactory`

Comment: Do you have that library?

Comment: Add some more details. Is this a plain Tomcat installation, or did you modify any configuration file or add libraries? When does it happen, just when you start Tomcat? Does it have anything to do with a webapp that you are deploying? What Java version are you using?